# Rails PostgreSQL get most duplicated property of objects saved and print it to screen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have `Ruby On Rails` app, and I have model called `Post` in it (generated by using `scaffolding`).

When people create new object instance of `Post` (there is one field called `name` and other one created automatically, called `id`) it saves these two fields: `title` and creates unique `id` in my database (I'm using `gem 'pg'` for database) for that row.

How can I achieve following result: "users have created a lot of `Posts` in my app, and I want to print most duplicated post title as one title (like, if there were 40 posts with title 'Violent Soho' and 20 posts with title 'DZ Deathrays' it would return 'Violent Soho' as an expected result) to my view."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
Post.group(:title).order('COUNT(id) DESC').limit(1).pluck(:title).first
```

Or:

```
Post.group(:title).order('COUNT(id) DESC').first.title
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you, spickermann! However, as I've noticed it selects by alphabet letters order?

Comment: And yes, how could I format output? At the moment it outputs in this pattern: ["Your_most_duplicated_post_title_goes_here"].
What I want, is output like this one: Your_most_duplicated_post_title_goes_here (without '[', ']' and '"' symbols)

Comment: Actually, in my view I just added "[0]" after my @variable and it worked like a charm. Thanks for your update :)